# Using the Extension Library Navigator

Tags: xpages, navigator, xpages-extlib

Does anyone know of a good tutorial or YouTube video that explains how to set up and use the Navigator in the IBM Xpages Extension Library?

It is a bit confusing with all the options, types of nodes, and Select & Submit Values. Hope to find something that shows the simple way to use this tool along with some of the Advanced capabilities.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Use more popular tags describing the technologies/languages you are using to help people to find and answer your question.

Comment: _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "_

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick youtube video where I show just the simplest use of it. enjoy

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adtyIAo3bZE

Is there anything specific you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully a good tutorial is the XPages Extension Library book. It goes into detail on all the various node types.